# Python - download google sheet - to csv file

Tags: python, google-sheets, export-to-csv, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm looking for a way to save a google sheet as csv on my computer..
I tried this:

```
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='client_secret.json')
sh = gc.open("sheets").worksheet("sheet1")

sh.to_csv("exported_file.csv")
```

How to make it work?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `gsheets` and `oauth2client` module for this.

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import gsheets

my_json = "client_secret.json"
my_sheet_url = f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{insert_id}"

SCOPE = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
CREDS = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(my_json, SCOPE)

sheets = gsheets.Sheets(CREDS)
sheet = sheets.get(my_sheet_url)
sheet[0].to_csv("export.csv")
```

This saves the first worksheet as a csv next to your `.py` file